# Output number of valid and invalid lines in text file read by java

Tags: java

im working on a program that reads through a text file showing bank transactions and then displays how many valid transactions where in the text file and how many where invalid. The text file looks like this:

```
W>10>12/11/2014
D>200>14/9/2014
W>1299>12/4/2013
D:345>12/3/2014
W10>14/9/2012
```

The top 3 transactions are all valid the bottom 2 are invalid.This is my code so far:

```
public void Tranctions(){

        String separator = ">";
        File inputfile = new File ("bank.txt");

        String[] Token;
        String aLine = "";

        System.out.println("Type"+"\tAmount"+"\t Date\n=========================================");

        try {
            Scanner filescan = new Scanner(inputfile);
            while (filescan.hasNext()){
                aLine = filescan.nextLine();

                Token = aLine.split(separator);

                if (Token.length == 3){
                    System.out.println(Token[0]+"\t €" +Token [1]+"\t"+Token[2]);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("String "+ aLine + "does not contain "+separator);
                }
            }

            filescan.close();
            System.out.println("End of transaction \n================================\n\n");

        } 

        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("problem "+e.getMessage());
        }


    }
```

}

I want the output to look something like this :

```
W        €10      12/11/2014
D        €200     14/9/2014
D        €1299    12/3/2014

Valid transactions : 3
Invalid transactions : 2
```

Been trying to get this to work but can't figure it out and can't find many threads covering this.. thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't expect us to compile and run your code to discover what the problem is. Tell us precisely what the problem is, including error messages you get, actual output vs. expected output, etc.

Comment: Don't bother wasting your time commenting if you are going to be useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't have other problems, i mean compile or crash, then this will be what you need

i will take the block of try{} and add/remove the code.

```
int totalValid=0,totalInvalid=0;

try {
            Scanner filescan = new Scanner(inputfile);
            while (filescan.hasNext()){
                aLine = filescan.nextLine();

                Token = aLine.split(separator);

                if (Token.length == 3){
                    System.out.println(Token[0]+"\t €" +Token [1]+"\t"+Token[2]);
                    ++totalValid;
                } else {
                    //REMOVED THE throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    ++totalInvalid;
                }
            }

                System.out.println("Valid transactions : " + totalValid);
                System.out.println("Invalid transactions : " + totalInvalid);

            filescan.close();
            System.out.println("End of transaction \n================================\n\n");

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("problem "+e.getMessage());
    }
```